# Object doesn't support property or method 'save'

Tags: javascript

I am getting error while calling `reportManager.save("/EditInitiatives.svc/SaveGridData");` method

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
    $('#saveReport, #save-report-bottom').click(function () {
        $.blockUI({ message: '<h4><img src="/Images/busy.gif" /> Saving your changes.<br/>This operation might impact several reports at once.<br/>Please be patient.</h4>' });
        uiController.disableSaveButton();
        reportManager.save("/EditInitiatives.svc/SaveGridData");
    });

    var reportManager = function () {
        var tableData = JSON.stringify(handsontable.getData());
        var input = JSON.stringify({ "input": tableData });
        alert("Data" +  input); 

        save = function(saveUrl) { 
            alert("save" + saveUrl);

            $.ajax({
                url: saveUrl,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: input, //returns all cells' data
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(res) {
                    if (res.result === 'ok') {
                        console.text('Data saved');
                    }                        
                    $.unblockUI();                            
                }, 
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }                       
            });
        }
    };
}
</script>
```

Comment: Functions are'nt automatically chainable, you'll need to define it as `this.save` and not a global, to do that ?

Comment: YOu need to expose `save` as an accessible method. add`                 return {
                     'save': save
                 }` at the end

Comment: @adeneo `save =` is under reportManager right?

Comment: @James123 Yes, but that is not how JavaScript works. It is a global variable since you missed the var.

Comment: should be `save : function(saveurl){ ... }`  instead of `=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not access it since `save` is a Global variable and not part of `reportManager`.

The reason why it is global is because you are missing the var in front of the variable. That puts it into the Global Namespace. It will not magically be hooked up to the block scope of the function. You would need to use an OO approach to get that to work. Some basic ideas are

```
function Report() {
     var x = 1;
    this.save = function () {
        alert("First: " + x);   
    }
}

var report = new Report();
report.save();


function report_2() {
     var x = 1;
    return {
        save : function () {
            alert("Second: " + x);   
        }
    }
}

var report2 = report_2();
report2.save();


var report_3 = (function () {
     var x = 1;

    var returnObj = {};
    returnObj.save = function () {
            alert("Third: " + x);   
    }

    return returnObj;


    //return {
    //    save  :  function() {
    //        alert("Third: " + x);   
    //    }
    //}
})();

report_3.save();
```

Fiddle of Examples: http://jsfiddle.net/5Zhsq/

Comment: better to put the save into the prototype of that class rather than using this.save

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the `save` function without `var` keyword; so it will be declared in global scope not as function of `reportManager`.

Even if you put the `var` keyword before `save` function then it's not accessible from outside of `reportManager` function `scope`. to expose it to public you need kinda `export` it. here is a simple pattern to do it:

```
 var reportManager = (function (self) {

      function save(saveUrl) { ... } //this function is not public yet

      self.save = save; //we are exporting the save function here
      return self; //now we are returning an object with save function

 })(reportManager || {});


 reportManager.save("your-param-here"); //Now use your function the way you want
```